Suppose that four lines are positioned so that every two are parallel and no three are coplanar. How many planes contain at least two of these lines?
Suppose that four lines are positioned so that every two are parallel and no three are coplanar. How many planes contain at least two of these lines?
Answer: 6 planes
I have no idea what this question is asking. I can't visualize it in my head. Consequently I can't visualize/understand why 6 planes contain at least two of these lines. Does the term "so that every two are parallel" mean randomly choosing any two lines?
Any help would be appreciated here to help me understand. If it's possible to visualize it even better. Thanks!

Think of a box, with the length much greater than the width or the height. Something like 
The long edges are your parallel lines. Now cut these with a plane perpendicular to those lines (one of the ends of the box). To see the planes formed by the parallel lines just look at the lines connecting the corners of the small end. You get 4 sides and two diagonals.

Show that

Every pair of parallel lines lie in a plane.
No trio of parallel lines lie in a plane.
Hence we have ${ 4 \choose 2 } = 6$ planes that contain (exactly) at least two of these lines.

